# visual studio 2010 no longer displaying html files

Tags: html, visual-studio-2010

It's been a few weeks since I fired up Visual Studio 2010 for my VC++ projects, but today I found it's no longer displaying the html (.htm) files in my solution. These are used for Help, Readme, etc. When I double click on a file for editing, a new source window is opened but it's totally blank. Everything else is working OK (display, builds etc.).

The actual file content is perfectly fine - it will open in a browser and display as expected. Any suggestions, please? All .htm files are behaving the same.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you open the file with F7 or SHIFT-F7 instead of a double click in the Solution Explorer?

Comment: I don't understand your suggestion. F7 is the shortcut to build the solution.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. In C# projects this is the default key for "View code" to see the actual source code of a file while Shift-F7 would render it depending on the file type (interpreting the HTML page in your case). I was assuming the key commands would be consistent over the supported languages in VS. But still, isn't there a corresponding functionality for VC++? This sounds to me like a corrupt or misconfigured file type/ file viewer association in VS.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if it opens the file when I double click on it in Solution Explorer, and displays a blank screen, then any other way isn't going to help. You would still have to single-click the file to select it, so I don't see the benefit of a function key to display it. HTML files aren't code, so I still fail to see the connection.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install(reinstall) Visual Web Developer component of Visual Studio 2010. It works for me :)